# Site doesn't hide address bar when scroll down in mobile browsers on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, reactjs

I made simple React app by "create-react-app" function (using hash-router, if  it will help), and deployed it on github-pages.
But, unfortunately, non of my pages doesn't hide address bar in mobile browsers when scroll down. Height of pages of course is more then 100%.
Similar problem was there: [Force hide address bar in Chrome on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647604/force-hide-address-bar-in-chrome-on-android)
, but there is no solution for me.
This is not a hybrid app or something else, it's just a site.
I don't need to hide address bar on load, just only when scrolling down, and pop up it when scrolling up.
I think it's just normal behaviour for site by default, isn't?
Maybe I need to add/delete something in my .html/.css/.jsx/.json files to make it workable (maybe I deleted something important for it, I don't know), but I can't find differences between my site and others sites, written on React or pure html/css/js stack.
I also tried to find information here and in internet, spent about 2 hours on it. I'm desperate.

Have learned following questions here:

[hide mobile browser address bar on chrome (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791705/hide-mobile-browser-address-bar-on-chrome-android)

[How to hide the toolbar in Chrome for Android tablets for a 100% high website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940047/how-to-hide-the-toolbar-in-chrome-for-android-tablets-for-a-100-high-website?rq=1)

[Hide address bar in android chrome browser with scroll down gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378059/hide-address-bar-in-android-chrome-browser-with-scroll-down-gesture)

[Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

[How to hide a mobile browser's address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395561/how-to-hide-a-mobile-browsers-address-bar)

Answer (score 4):

Found a cause. Hope it will help someone who did similar amusing mistake as I.

The point is that I embedded following code to avoid problem with background (it didn't cover whole area of page):

```
html, body, #root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;}
```

It blocks growth of height, of course, despite visually content is more then 100%. And even if I remove **#root** out of this ruleset, it wouldn't help, although **#root** would be bigger than html and body.

Solution is to set min-sizes instead (in addition to removing #root, of course):

```
html, body {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;}
```

Sorry for disturbing, guys)